# Question about limit.

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

My question is that in my practical sheet I have been given a question which says show that limit doesn't exist and question is

$f(x,y)= \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2-x}$   s.t $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$

My question is: can I put $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y=-x$ and show that limits on these paths are different so limit doesn't exist?

If not so please show me how to do that?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's legitimate to consider paths where $y$ is a function of $x$, such that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} y(x) = 0$, and if the limit along two such paths is different, it follows that $\lim\limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a valid approach. If you can show that the limit depends on the path of approach, then the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: *Comment:* With this technique, it is often fruitful to put $y=mx$ and show that the limit depends on $m$. This is a specific but often simpler variety of the same thing. Here, the paths of approach are radial.